# Job satisfaction talk at a startup

Tags: startup

So I'm currently working for a startup, we only have 10 guys in service. WHen I started at this job it was fun I got a lot of freedom, I needed to setup everything in my area (I'm the only one doing my kind of job in this company). But now after almost 2 years I feel kind of stuck. I don't get much appreciation, don't have lot's of challenges. And one part of my job my boss doesn't really care that much I get the feeling if I do well or not.

I'm kinda stuck on what is the next move. Should I talk to my boss about it. Or maybe should go to another company because I'm early in my career?

Comment: VTC, career advice is out of scope.  We're not in a position to tell you what is best for your career

Comment: What sort of profession are you in? Is it normal for someone in that line to spend 2 years in a job before moving on?

Comment: I'm a Quality Engineer in IT

Comment: Try reading the book "what color is your parachute" as I think it can help you work through that feeling of being stuck in your career.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I talk to my boss about it?

**Yes** you should talk to your manager about this.  I would inquire about additional opportunities to take on more responsibility as these are *usually readily available in a start up*.

> Or maybe should go to another company because I'm early in my career?

Ultimately if you are left with out any growth opportunities, and you have attempted to work with your manager, then yes it may be time for you to move on to a more challenging opportunity in another organization.